# - ORA-06550: line 9, column 12: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbdrop;
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbcreate;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   ORDER_ID     ORDERS.ODID%TYPE;
   COMPANY_NAME ORDERS.CNAME%TYPE;
   ORDER_DATE   ORDERS.ODATE%TYPE;
   CURSOR ord_cursor IS 
        SELECT ODID, CNAME, ODATE
            FROM ORDERS
            WHERE ODER_DATE< TRUNC(SYSDATE);
           FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
BEGIN
   OPEN ord_cursor;
   LOOP
     FETCH ord_cursor into ORDER_ID, COMPANY_NAME, ORDER_DATE;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('           ');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ODER ID: '|| TO_CHAR(Order_Id));
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'ODER DATE: ' || ORDER_DATE );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMPANY NAME: '||  COMPANY_NAME );
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------------');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------------');
     IF ord_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN 
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE ord_cursor;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FETCH" when expecting one of the following:

begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
    current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
       WHERE ODER_DATE< TRUNC(SYSDATE);
       FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

is wrong; either remove semi-colon in the first line (if your database supports `FETCH` clause), or entire second line.

---

Shorter version of your code is something like this (I don't have your tables so I fabricated one, based on Scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> create table orders as
  2  select empno ordid, ename cname, hiredate odate
  3  from emp
  4  where deptno = 10;

Table created.
```

Code itself:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in
  3      (select ordid, cname, odate
  4       from orders
  5       where odate < trunc(sysdate)
  6         and rownum <= 5
  7      )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line('------------');
 10      dbms_output.put_line('Order ID   = ' || cur_r.ordid);
 11      dbms_output.put_line('Order date = ' || to_char(cur_r.odate, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
 12      dbms_output.put_line('Company    = ' || cur_r.cname);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
------------
Order ID   = 7782
Order date = 09.06.1981
Company    = CLARK
------------
Order ID   = 7839
Order date = 17.11.1981
Company    = KING
------------
Order ID   = 7934
Order date = 23.01.1982
Company    = MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: you mean change all my code into your comment?I tried, but it doesn't  work.

Comment: Should I also use the part after my DECLARE?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use anything but code I posted (the BEGIN-END block). If it "doesn't work", please, specify *what* does not work. Any error? If so, which one?

Comment: Right, @Steven, there were two errors - comma behind ODATE and COMPANY_NAME instead of CNAME in DBMS_OUTPUT call. Fixed; moreover, I posted whole example which shows that it *works*, if correctly used. As I said: I don't have your tables so - fix column names if necessary.

Comment: The errors happen not at very beginning, line 4 here refers to SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; line 3 refers to DECLARE.    Full error report: ORA-06550: line 4, column 6:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06550: line 3, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Now the only problem is PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COMPANY_NAME": invalid identifier.But I checked my data , but the name is called "company_name" indeed. I don't know why it is like this. Is there have something to do with it because "company_name" is a foreign key while the other twos are not?

Comment: Just change all CNAME in my code with COMPANY_NAME.

Comment: WOW!! It really works now, bur why there is not any order-id or order-date I want coming out just like your:  Order ID   = 7782
Order date = 09.06.1981
Company    = CLARK      ???

Comment: You mean, there's no output at all? Did you SET SERVEROUTPUT ON?

Comment: YES,I did SET SERVEROUTPUT ON.It says: "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.", but no output at all. Every time I run it again, it shows :"SQL>  12      dbms_output.put_line('Company    = ' || cur_r.company_name);"  again.

Comment: It seems that you didn't terminate the PL/SQL block. The last line must be slash `/` (see line #15 in my code).

Comment: Oh, i see! But this time it only shows me a "/" but nothing else. Hahaha

Comment: Huh, that's strange. As you can see in my example, it actually *works* and produces result. Can you try it in some other tool, like SQL Developer? The `SQL>` prompt means that you did it in SQL*Plus, right? If everything is set OK, it just *should* work ...

Comment: I am always using sqldeveloper from the start to the end.I don't think this is a easy case  it is more complex, so i ask another question , if you have time I am happy if you come and answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61244471/no-output-when-use-sqldeveloper-and-no-errors-at-all

Comment: Right; I think I understand now. You copy/pasted my whole SQL*Plus session. You have to omit line numbers and prompts. I replied in another question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Your query ends before the `FETCH` clause and that is the issue.

You can use simple `FOR loop` and string concatenation as follows:

```
BEGIN
   FOR CUR IN (SELECT 'ODER ID: '|| TO_CHAR(ODID) || CHR(10)
                      || 'ODER DATE: ' || ODATE || CHR(10)
                      || 'COMPANY NAME: ' ||  CNAME || CHR(10)
                      || '------------' AS STR
                 FROM ORDERS
                WHERE ODER_DATE< TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY)
    LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CUR.STR);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: Should I also use the part after my DECLARE?

Comment: Well, yes, Tejash - you really need to handle exception as you closed cursor you never opened. Though, WHEN OTHERS is mostly always *wrong* without RAISE, and such a "handler" is pretty much useless as Oracle would display the error message anyway.

Comment: Ahhh!!! That was line which I forgot to delete from original question. Updated the answer now!!