# PL/SQL: ORA-00904: invalid identifier &PL/SQL: Statement ignored&PLS-00364: loop index variable use is invalid

Tags: sql, oracle

```
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbdrop;
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbcreate;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
 begin
     for cur_r in
      (select order_id, company_name, order_date
        from orders
        where order_date < trunc(sysdate)
          and rownum <= 5
        )
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line('------------');
       dbms_output.put_line('Order ID   = ' || cur_r.order_id);
       dbms_output.put_line('Order date = ' || to_char(cur_r.order_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
       dbms_output.put_line('Company    = ' || cur_r.company_name);
     end loop;
   end;
  /
```

Error report -

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 27: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COMPANY_NAME":
>    invalid identifier
>   ORA-06550: line 3, column 10: PL/SQL: SQL Statement
>    ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 49: PLS-00364: loop index variable 'CUR_R' use is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 10, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 58: PLS-00364: loop index variable 'CUR_R' use is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 8: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   ORA-06550: line 12, column 49: PLS-00364: loop index variable 'CUR_R' use is invalid
>   ORA-06550: line 12, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Here is the ORDERS table

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
    ORDER_ID        NUMBER(9)   NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER_CODE   VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
    EMPLOYEE_ID     NUMBER(9)   NOT NULL,
    ORDER_DATE      DATE        NOT NULL,
    REQUIRED_DATE   DATE,
    SHIPPED_DATE    DATE,
    SHIP_VIA        VARCHAR(40),
    FREIGHT         NUMBER(10,2)    DEFAULT 0,
    SHIP_NAME       VARCHAR(40),
    SHIP_ADDRESS    VARCHAR(60),
    SHIP_CITY       VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_REGION     VARCHAR(15),
    SHIP_POSTAL_CODE    VARCHAR(10),
    SHIP_COUNTRY    VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ORDERS PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_CODE FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_CODE) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_CODE),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_ID FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID),  
    CONSTRAINT FK_SHIP_VIA FOREIGN KEY (SHIP_VIA) REFERENCES SHIPPER(COMPANY_NAME)  
);
```

Comment: HELL YEAH. Thank you bro , I will revise my question

Comment: Provide output of `DESC orders` in your question.

Comment: @APC Yes, I've show the table ORDERS in the edited queaation

Comment: @LalitKumar Sorry, what is a "output of DESC"? I've given out the tons of errors be output.

Comment: DESC is a SQL\*Plus command which describes the table. Posting the CREATE TABLE is the same thing.

Comment: Incidentally in Oracle you should be using the VARCHAR2 datatype.

Comment: Although internally Oracle will treat it as VARCHAR2, but highly recommended not to use VARCHAR to avoid any issues in future if default functionality changes. `DESC` would show the type as `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Remove all references to company_name from your PL/SQL block and your code should execute fine.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer you can't copy/paste what I wrote (previously) in SQL*Plus; you'd omit line numbers (and `SQL>` prompts) and use this only:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  for cur_r in
    (select order_id, ship_via as company_name, order_date
     from orders
     where order_date < trunc(sysdate)
       and rownum <= 5
    )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('------------');
    dbms_output.put_line('Order ID   = ' || cur_r.order_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Order date = ' || to_char(cur_r.order_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
    dbms_output.put_line('Company    = ' || cur_r.company_name);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this one but there is a lot of errors.It says :"PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COMPANY_NAME": invalid identifier". But I check the data it is "COMPANY_NAME" indeed.

Comment: Could you post ORDERS table description? Not as a comment - edit the original message you posted (the question).

Comment: OK, There are three sql files i have to complete the the task of seekinng order_id, order_time and company_name, they are dbdrop.sql, dbcreate.sql and  dbload.sql. It seems like i forget to import the dbload.sql which is used for loading all the data into the empty dbcreate. I didn't  create any other ORDERS table except the very first 2 lines:"  @C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbdrop;
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbcreate;"

Comment: I will show you the ORDERS table in dbcreat .sql in the edited question

Comment: There's no column COMPANY_NAME in the ORDERS table, hence the error. It means that it is probably in some other table, which means that you'll have to **JOIN** two (or more) tables to get data you need. **OR**: as there's a foreign key from ORDERS to SHIPPER and the key column is COMPANY_NAME, substitute it with SHIP_VIA: `select order_id, ship_via as company_name, order_date`

Comment: Oh my god , I understand , i thought COMPANY_NAME is already a foreigh key.

Comment: OMG, it shows me the successful output. Thank you so much little foot !

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 27: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "COMPANY_NAME": invalid identifier

This indicates that your query is referencing a column which doesn't exist in the table. Now that you have posted the description of ORDERS we can see that indeed it doesn't have a column called COMPANY_NAME. Because the query is invalid the cursor is invalid and so references to the cursor are also invalid. That's why you have so many compilation errors. It is common in programming for one syntax error to trigger a whole bunch more.

However, ORDERS does have a foreign key to CUSTOMERS. So probably what you need to do is join to that table in your cursor query:

```
for cur_r in
      (select o.order_id, c.company_name, o.order_date
        from orders o
             join customers c on c.customer_code = o.customer_code
        where o.order_date < trunc(sysdate)
          and rownum <= 5
        )
     loop
```